# How to get specific object during creation records in APEX

Tags: apex

I have a question regarding adding appriopriate object.

After user created a CAR__c object trigger should create a new object TYPE__c with specific data.
During creation CAR__c object user have to choose one subtype for eg. ASTRA.
When he save the record object TYPE__c should be created with ER Type = ASTRA

```
Set<String> erTypes = new Set<String>{'ASTRA', 'FOCUS', 'CHR'};

for(CAR__c car: carList) {
    if(erTypes .contains(car.esType__c) {
        Type__c type = new Type__c (
            Name = car.abc__c,
            erType__c = <How to get appriopriate value when user choose eg. FOCUS? > This is a lookup field. We have a another object called VEHICLE__c with the same values like in Set erTypes. So here should be object VEHICLE__c.Id with value which user selected during creation a car object.
        );
        insert type;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is query for that value. For instance:

`VEHICLE__c theVehicle = [SELECT Id FROM VEHICLE__c WHERE Name=:car.esType__c];`

Now that you have the instance of `theVehicle` that you were looking for you can reference its Id like so `erType__c = theVehicle.Id;`

However the bigger problem you hjave is that you are doing a DML statement inside a for loop. Here's how you can refine your code to avoid hitting any [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm).

```
Set<String> esTypes = new Set<String>();
for(CAR__c car: carList) {
    esTypes.add(car.esType__c);
}

Map<String, Id> vehiclesMap = new Map<String, Id>();
for (VEHICLE__c theVehicle: [SELECT Id, Name FROM VEHICLE__c WHERE Name=:esTypes]) {
    vehiclesMap.put(theVehicle.Name, theVehicle.Id);
}

List<Type__c> theTypes = new List<Type__c>();
for(CAR__c car: carList) {
    if(erTypes.contains(car.esType__c) {
        Type__c carType = new Type__c (
            Name = car.abc__c,
            erType__c = vehiclesMap.get(car.esType__c);
        );
        theTypes.add(carType);
    }
}
insert theTypes;
```